# How to save added data into database with output JSON in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a field that can be multiple when user will add another data. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

***Here's my html code***

```
<tr>
                <td>経歴（学歴）</td>
                <td>
                    <div id="academic">
                        <select name="c_ac_year">
                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="c_ac_month">
                            <option value="January">January</option>
                            <option value="February">February</option>
                            <option value="March">March</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" id="form-control" name="c_ac_desc">
                    </div>
                    <div id="new_chq"></div>
                    <a href="" class="add">Add</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

When click add, another set of fields will be added. How will I save these data in the database in array form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use php array[] input in HTML side as like this :

```
<div id="academic">
   <select name="c_ac_year[]">
      <option value="2019">2019</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
  </select>
  <select name="c_ac_month[]">
      <option value="January">January</option>
      <option value="February">February</option>
      <option value="March">March</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" id="form-control" name="c_ac_desc[]">
```

In PHP side, You can get value :

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $years = $_POST['c_ac_year']; //or $this->input->post('c_ac_year');
    $months = $_POST['c_ac_month']; // or $this->input->post('c_ac_month');
    $descs = $_POST['c_ac_desc']; // or $this->input->post('c_ac_desc');
     $response = array();
    foreach($years as $key=> $year)
    {
       $response[$key]['year'] = $year;
       $response[$key]['month'] = $months[$key];
       $response[$key]['desc'] = $descs[$key];
    }
    echo json_encode($response); exit;
}
```

Output will be :

```
  [
{
year: "2019",
month: "January",
desc: "value 1",
},
{
year: "2018",
month: "February",
desc: "value 2",
},
{
year: "2017",
month: "March",
desc: "value 3",
},
]
```

Comment: thank you so much sir. for your code. it really helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use array names in the html like `name="c_ac_year[]"`

Then in controller `$this->input->post('c_ac_year');` will be an array and you can use indexing to get the other associated fields for that row

Comment: thank you for your answer sir. I'm sorry but how to use indexing sir?

Comment: For example `foreach($this->input->post('c_ac_year') as $index=>$value)`

Comment: okay sir. But how to get this sir {"2019" , "January", "comment 1"}, {"2018" , "February", "comment 2"}. This should be the output that can be saved in database. Sorry sir i am comfusing.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your answer. Almost fix my code with the help of @ni3solanki and your explaination sir.